# Is there a way to log read/write events on EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, amazon-cloudtrail

I am working on a project that requires an auditable log read/write events of hosted files. I have been looking at the CloudTrail logs but it doesn't seem to capture EFS read/write events. It looks as though you can setup trail to record read/writes for S3 though.

Can anybody advise if it is possible to capture these events for EFS?

Comment: AWS CloudTrail can track API calls made to EFS, but these are only calls to create/manage the filesystem: [Logging Amazon EFS API Calls with AWS CloudTrail - Amazon Elastic File System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/logging-using-cloudtrail.html). It does not include logging of file access/updates. Logging such updates to a disk is quite unusual -- I can't think of a time when I have seen logging of access to a disk or filesystem. Can you tell us more about the "hosted files" you with to audit? Perhaps you could deploy from a repository?

Comment: The files are DB files from a Postgres DB. We have been requested to provide a way to verify/monitor that the files being read/copied or modified through any other means other than through our API. Basically to prove the files haven't been copied or tampered with manually.

Comment: It would be hard to prove they weren't accessed. Modification could be tracked with checksums on the files.